# Replace a part of the cell with another columns cell in excel

Tags: excel

I needed some help with this excel task, I need to replace a part of the cell in column A with corresponding cell value in column B. [excel worksheet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ18V.png)

your help in appreciated

Comment: [surya gopal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10501895/surya-gopal), TEST LEAD at HIDUS TECHNOLOGIES

Answer (score 1):

SUBSTITUTE(A1,"SUBSIDY_SWITCH", B1)

Answer (score 1):

There  are  different methods in excel sheet like  find, replace,SUBSTITUTE having some params 
this can be  done  by SUBSTITUTE or REPLACE method

```
=SUBSTITUTE(where to search,"text to replace", "text with replace")
```

in place of string literals there can b columns

**OR**

> =REPLACE(A1,FIND(B1,A1),LEN(B1),C1)

this REPLACE method replace B1 text with C1 of A1
A1 has larger string, B1 which one  to replace, C1 with which one to replace 
formula written in D1 
[image: image is attached]

[you can see here more about it.](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/substitute.php)

Comment: You're welcome
if answer  is  helpful, vote  for Best answer